# CSS float image align

Tags: css-position

I need to add this image [image] at the end of a line, in this way

[image]

Style:

```
h4 { border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-size: 1.6em;}
```

Code that I did:

```
<h4>Socializziamo <img src="flourish-decoration.png" 
    style="position:relative; display:inline-block; float:right;bottom:-7px;" />
</h4>
```

Is there a better way, because my solution sometimes does not works...

Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative to [ggbhat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206694/926710). The approach here is to apply relative positioning on the heading and absolute positioning on the nested image.

#### HTML

```
<h4>
    Socializziamo <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/68LQd.png" />
</h4>
```

#### CSS

```
h4 { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    font-size: 1.6em;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/LqvTx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use :after psuedo element for adding background image .

```
h4
{ 
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
width:100px;
}


h4:after {
content:"";
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/68LQd.png)no-repeat;
width: 30px;  
height: 30px;
background-position:68% 25%;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo:[http://jsfiddle.net/LqvTx/ ]

Comment: The decoration image is not well aligned with the underline

Comment: @Riccardo79 you can change the background position, so that align the image as you required.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but avik's solution is quite easy and portable